# Filling in an 8x8 minesweeper grid with mines (Day 6: Anti-Mines - A better introduction)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

<sub>*Disclaimer: ascii85(Z85 (ZeroMQ) encoding)(`q/uX%C{3ZqAV/mrBrCjcBAzkmxcqqfwGU@mDu%ysazbLjavGT-at$uXB-X:KwPI%8A+5Q7e*9.dCvtLnBAhUvzF78lzY&X7BrCWswGUS1zeA#%yAN.qaAz44B8L@8vR*rjCw?IqasIqBzEWl2nG.XPC4CLsBrCajzE<@iz/66cxLzu%az++cwGV8dx(+zawOb>3wHO:yzY<dnwGV57xK$Z%y?j-kx(4PdAb](avpB4#ayX[8l$7u-hxW9Wwmo:avqYP#l$7u-hY#KDwfr&OBz(2mA=M8xazCBgBzb98aAIEzzE^/hA+eW2z/e#)y?kj`)*</sub>

---

Now, I know that I have already introduced anti-mines many times before, but today, I feel like I should give you a better introduction. The reason being, I feel like I just never gave a reasonable intro to anti-mines. So, today, there will only be anti-mines. However, here's the thing. There are a few missing tiles that contain numbers that you will need to deduce where they are.

The grid:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2 |  |  | -1 | -2 |  |  |  |
|  | -3 | -2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| -3 | -3 | -2 | -1 |  |  | -6 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | -2 |  | -3 |
|  |  | -7 |  |  |  | -2 |  |
| -3 |  |  |  |  |  | -3 | -3 |
| -3 |  |  |  |  | -2 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | -2 |  | -3 |

What I have deleted:

> -1x3
>
> -2x2
>
> -3x6
>
> -4x2
>
> -5x1
>
> -8x1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we try to solve what we can

> Cross = No mine; Flag = mine; Circled number = that number is satisfied.
>  [image: initial solve]

Then we try to fill in the numbers

> [image: filling in the numbers]
>  Here we need to note that we're running out of "-1". So the "?" has to be "-2".

Then the rest is easy

> [image: final solution]

Thank you for the nice puzzle!